# Initiating chrome browser for Selenium on Windows 2019 causing errors

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting "IllegalState driver executable must exist ... " after updating to windows 2019 (the code worked fine on windows 2012). The line
"driver = new ChromeDriver();" is causing the error in the code block below

```
`import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

@Test(groups = {"open browser, CreatedByFilter"})

public class InitiateBrowser {

    
    
    //public static WebDriver driver;
    public static ChromeDriver driver;
    static ArrayList<String> notificationArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public void openBrowser() 
        {
        System.out.println("Initiating chrome browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        DesiredCapabilities cp = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cp.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        options.merge(cp);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            System.out.println("Browser Initiated");
            String browserNotification = "Browser Initiated";
            notificationArray.add(browserNotification);
     
    }
    
}`
```

Comment: Please add the entire `stacktrace` in the question.

Comment: remove all those DesiredCapabilities lines... not needed, and you aren't setting anything there anyway.  All the options you need will be in ChromeOptions...

Comment: @DiegoBorba
Initiating chrome browser
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.267 s <<< FAILURE! - in stepDefinitions.InitiateBrowser
[ERROR] stepDefinitions.InitiateBrowser.openBrowser  Time elapsed: 0.31 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe
        at stepDefinitions.InitiateBrowser.openBrowser(InitiateBrowser.java:41)

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   InitiateBrowser.openBrowser:41 » IllegalState The driver executable must exist...

Comment: @DiegoBorba
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.133 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-30T12:24:15-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project CucumberFramework: There are test failures.
[ERROR]

Comment: I mean, [edit] your question and put the sacktrace.

Comment: @DiegoBorba
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\QaTests\eclipse-workspace\GroupTestTroubleshoot\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

Comment: @DiegoBorba

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: @pcalkins

I removed it and getting the same error. Here is the updated code:

System.out.println("Initiating chrome browser");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
String browserNotification = "Browser Initiated";
notificationArray.add(browserNotification);

Comment: you may want to do something with that ChromeOptions() object... though that has nothing to do with your error.  It can't find this file: C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe  Check to see that it exists, and that the user running this code has execute privileges.  Sometimes a user only has permissions in their own user directories.